# Buzzing sound from PSU on some startups but not always

Tags: power-supply, noise

I've just bought a second hand Dell tower PC. Upon switching it on, it sometimes immediately makes this buzzing/drilling sound. Switching it off and then on again resolves the issue (which I find intriguing).
If you feel inclined, you can listen to the noise [here](https://youtu.be/MosxjINPwPI). I'm hoping maybe it's just because I had it in my car on its side and maybe it will magically disappear given that it doesn't happen every time.
If I bring it back to the shop, I know they will exchange it, but it's a bit of a hassle and I really liked this PC. Based on my description, what would my options be?

Comment: If the shop will exchange it, that is easier that ordering and replacing the power supply. The noise is internal and not much you can do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely the fan(s) in the power supply. If you feel comfortable with repairs, and **are willing to risk that the shop won't take the machine back** if your attempted repair goes bad, then look for one of two things:

- A wire rubbing against the fan blade, which is easily relocated out of contact, or
- A bad fan, which likely would need to be replaced.

**N.B.** There are *high voltages* inside the PSU, possibly stored by capacitors even after the PSU has been unplugged. Unless your proficient in electrical repairs, return the PC.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, any way I can discharge all capacitors once removed plug? If not, I won't touch it, I'm not trained for electrical or electronic repairs. PS : did even the video leave you thinking it was a fan rather than the PSU?

Comment: There are fans *inside* the PSU, and one might be the culprit.

Comment: Well, you were right !